# Why is getAddressDetails() sending the return last?

Tags: lightning-web-components, integration, vlocity

I'm calling a  Vlocity Integration Procedures by lwc when the user click in a simple button.
I need to receive the `addressRespose` before any result to call other functions, but `getAddressDetails()` is always giving the "Success" and the response last. Can someone help me?

**LOG**

```
SUCCESS2 undefined

params
input: "{\"postalCode\":\"12345\",\"streetNr\":\"5\"}"
options: "{}"
sClassName: "vlocity_cmt.IntegrationProcedureService"
sMethodName: "GetAddress"

SOME MSG TEST

SUCCESS { the result of the Vlocity Integration Procedures }
```

**buttonlwc.js**

```
import { LightningElement, api, track} from 'lwc';
import { OmniscriptActionCommonUtil } from "vlocity_cmt/omniscriptActionUtils";
import { getNamespaceDotNotation } from "vlocity_cmt/omniscriptInternalUtils";
import { OmniscriptBaseMixin } from 'vlocity_cmt/omniscriptBaseMixin';

export default class buttonlwc extends OmniscriptBaseMixin(LightningElement) {
    
    @api streetnr;
    @api postalcode;

    _ns = getNamespaceDotNotation();
    _actionUtilClass;

    connectedCallback() {
        this._actionUtil = new OmniscriptActionCommonUtil();
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.callModal();
        
    }

    callModal() {
        this.addressRespose = getAddressDetails();
        console.log("SOME MSG TEST");
        this.template.querySelector("c-modal-lwc").callModal(this.addressRespose);
    }
    
    getAddressDetails() {

        this.paramsGetAddress = {
            streetNr: this.streetnr,
            postalCode: this.postalcode,
        };

    let params = {
      input: JSON.stringify(this.paramsGetAddress),
      sClassName: `${this._ns}IntegrationProcedureService`,
      sMethodName: "GetAddress",
      options: "{}",
    };

    this._actionUtil
      .executeAction(params, null, this, null, null)

      .then((response) => {
        response;
        console.log("SUCCESS", response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error, "ERROR");
      });
    console.log("SUCCESS 2 ", this.response);
    console.log("params", params);
  }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, what you're seeing is the expected results. When you call asynchronous code, the code runs at some point later, after the main execution. We can demonstrate this with something like:

```
function a() {
  const b = new Promise((resolve, reject) => resolve('step 4')).then(console.log)
  console.log('step 2')
  return b
}
console.log('step 1')
const result = a()
console.log(result)
console.log('step 3')
```

You'll get this output:

```
step 1
step 2
Promise {<pending>}
step 3
step 4
```

As you can see, the `then` statement is called after everything else finishes. That's just how asynchronous code works.

The easiest way to fix this is to use async/await to force the order of execution:

```
  async callModal() {
    this.addressRespose = await getAddressDetails();
    console.log("SOME MSG TEST");
    this.template.querySelector("c-modal-lwc").callModal(this.addressRespose);
  }

  async getAddressDetails() {
    this.paramsGetAddress = {
      streetNr: this.streetnr,
      postalCode: this.postalcode,
    };

    let params = {
      input: JSON.stringify(this.paramsGetAddress),
      sClassName: `${this._ns}IntegrationProcedureService`,
      sMethodName: "GetAddress",
      options: "{}",
    };

    try {
      const response = await this._actionUtil.executeAction(
        params,
        null,
        this,
        null,
        null
      );
      console.log("SUCCESS", response);
      console.log("SUCCESS 2 ", this.response);
      console.log("params", params);
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error, "ERROR");
    }
  }
```

The `await` keyword makes the code wait until the Promise calls resolve/reject, and the `async` keyword converts a function to a Promise implicitly (and is required to use `await`). You still need to remember to use the `return` statement, though, which was also missing in your original code.

Comment: Thanks, but now  the other LWC "c-modal-lwc", is recieving this.addressRespose = null. Could you help me?

Comment: c-modal-lwc is recieving this.addressRespose = Proxy {}
[[Handler]]: Object
[[Target]]: Object
[[IsRevoked]]: false

Comment: @Caroline Proxy is just a Lightning Locker Service wrapper. You can inspect the `[[Target]]` object to see the data within. Accessing the data normally also works.

Comment: How can I use this Target in the methods? I tried JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(addressResponse) but i failed...

Comment: @Caroline You don't use it in the JavaScript, `[[Target]]` is just how the data is stored. Doublecheck the spelling of your variable names, remember to use `this` as appropriate, and also remember that JS is case-sensitive.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sorry, I didn't undestand...I created a new question about it https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/367599/how-do-i-send-data-from-a-proxy-to-a-function-in-lwc