# How do I send data from a Proxy to a function in LWC?

Tags: lightning-web-components, proxy

I'm trying to send a data of a response in a function like `function(response)` in my LWC, but the response is a Proxy container with format like `Proxy {}[[Handler]]: En[[Target]]: Array(0)[[IsRevoked]]: false`

On opening the `[[Target]]`, and after on expanding the `originalTarget` , my data is shown.

How do I get this data to send properly to the function in LWC ?

I tried `const objUncovered = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(objWhichIsCoveredWithProxy));`
but it only works in the `console.log()`.

**EDIT: @Sebastian Kessel, this.addressRespose is sending like a proxy to "c-modal-lwc"**

```
import { LightningElement, api, track} from 'lwc';
import { OmniscriptActionCommonUtil } from "vlocity_cmt/omniscriptActionUtils";
import { getNamespaceDotNotation } from "vlocity_cmt/omniscriptInternalUtils";
import { OmniscriptBaseMixin } from 'vlocity_cmt/omniscriptBaseMixin';

export default class buttonlwc extends OmniscriptBaseMixin(LightningElement) {
    
    @api streetnr;
    @api postalcode;

    _ns = getNamespaceDotNotation();
    _actionUtilClass;

    connectedCallback() {
        this._actionUtil = new OmniscriptActionCommonUtil();
    }

    handleClick() {
        this.callModal();
        
    }

async callModal() {
    this.addressRespose = await getAddressDetails();

    //HERE CALL THE OTHER LWC modalLwc
    this.template.querySelector("c-modal-lwc").callModal(this.addressRespose);
  }

  async getAddressDetails() {
    this.paramsGetAddress = {
      streetNr: this.streetnr,
      postalCode: this.postalcode,
    };

    let params = {
      input: JSON.stringify(this.paramsGetAddress),
      sClassName: `${this._ns}IntegrationProcedureService`,
      sMethodName: "GetAddress",
      options: "{}",
    };

    try {
      const response = await this._actionUtil.executeAction(
        params,
        null,
        this,
        null,
        null
      );
      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error, "ERROR");
    }
  }
```

**modalLwc.js**

```
import { LightningElement, api, track } from "lwc";
import { OmniscriptActionCommonUtil } from "vlocity_cmt/omniscriptActionUtils";
import { getNamespaceDotNotation } from "vlocity_cmt/omniscriptInternalUtils";
import { OmniscriptBaseMixin } from "vlocity_cmt/omniscriptBaseMixin";


export default class modalLwc extends OmniscriptBaseMixin(LightningElement) {
    
  @track columns = ["", "ABC", "XYZ"];
  @track rows;

  _ns = getNamespaceDotNotation();
  _actionUtilClass;
  
  @track openmodal = false;

  connectedCallback() {
    this._actionUtil = new OmniscriptActionCommonUtil();
  }

  @api
  callModal(addressRespose) {
    
    /*I RECIEVE addressResponse LIKE A PROXY AND WHEN IT GET IN THE LINE BELOW, THE CHROME INSPECTOR SAYS:
    Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e[Nn] is not a function */

    this.rows = this.getRows(addressRespose); 
   
    if (this.rows) {
      this.showModal();
    } else {
       //Call another functions
    }
  }
  getRows(addressesResponse) {
     let addressesList = addressesResponse;
     return addressesList;
}
   showModal() {
        this.openmodal = true;
    }
    closeModal() {
        this.openmodal = false;
    }
}
```

The error em Chrome console: The error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: e[Nn] is not a function

Ps: the modal doesn't open either

Comment: Can you add all the relevant code?

Comment: The point with a proxy is that you can treat it as if it were just the value itself. No need to mess around. There is just one difference; proxies returned by wires and received through `@api` properties from outside the component are read only and must be cloned to make them writable.

Comment: @SebastianKessel I put the code on my question

Comment: @PhilW what do you mean by "cloned"? Like it: let abc = myProxy ?

Comment: No, that doesn't clone the value, it is simply another reference. Take a look [here](https://www.w3docs.com/snippets/javascript/how-to-clone-a-javascript-object.html).

Comment: So, what is the specific problem and can you add a comment in the code that is causing that problem?

Comment: @PhilW see if it's better now

Comment: Still not sure where in the code you have the error. Please highlight it. BTW, I would say it is better to use decoupled callback functions in promises over use of async and await. Though that is personal opinion.

Comment: @PhillW I put 2 comments in the codes... I hope it's better now